# Error with Firefox on Centos 7.1 and Xvfb

Tags: centos7

I'm getting this error when I try to run firefox using xvfb-run:

```
Xlib:  extension "RANDR" missing on display ":99".
/usr/lib64/firefox/firefox: symbol lookup error: /lib64/libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0: undefined symbol: g_type_check_instance_is_fundamentally_a
```

I'm using a Vagrant box with epel and ius repositories enabled but also if I explicitly disable them when I install firefox or xvfb with yum I have the same problem.

I really don't know what to do now. Do you have any suggestion?

Thanks!

Comment: Update your system.

Comment: Thanks @MichaelHampton, that actually worked! I'm not an export with CentOS and I was under the impression that yum should have installed all needed updates automatically. Is it not intended to work like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to update my system with the command:

```
yum upgrade
```